# Web services and RPC

Tags: web-services, xml-rpc, rpc

Hi
I have misunderstanding in the two terms
What is the technical differences between Web Service and RPC ?
can we consider a WS as a XML RPC and is it a xmlRpc  ?

thanks

Comment: XML-RPC is an old protocol that is rarely used anymore. It was superseded by the SOAP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Both terms are somewhat vague, and do not refer to specific technologies. [Web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) can be used to make [RPCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) using [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL) or one of a few standards which are roughly equivalent, such as [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA), [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), or [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model).

WSDL can be used to describe a SOAP web service, or (in WSDL 2.0) a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) one.